# Routing in servant

Tags: haskell, servant

I am using the Servant in a Haskell project. Below is my source code:

```
type MyAPI 
    = "base" :>  "page1.html":> Get '[HTML] H.Html 
    :<|> "base" :> "page2.html" :> Get '[HTML] H.Html 
    :<|> "base" :> "page3.html" :> Get '[HTML] H.Html 

serverAPI = pageH1 :<|> pageH2 :<|> pageH3
```

For each of the methods (pageH1, pageH2, pageH3) there is a general action. This general action determines whether it is possible to load pages (pageH1, pageH2, pageH3). I want to write a listener for the path "base/" and afte that move on next routes (or don`t move). Like next:

```
type MyAPI 
        = "base" :> ............... 
        :<|> "base" :>  "page1.html":> Get '[HTML] H.Html 
        :<|> "base" :> "page2.html" :> Get '[HTML] H.Html 
        :<|> "base" :> "page3.html" :> Get '[HTML] H.Html 

    serverAPI = page :<|> pageH1 :<|> pageH2 :<|> pageH3
```

Is it possible to implement it?

Comment: Sounds like what you're looking for might be WAI middleware; Perhaps [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-middleware-auth)?

Comment: There is a servan-auth package, but it is limited to JWT or cookies for the moment.
https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant-auth